# How to create dynamic/chained dropdown in codeigniter for the same table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to create dynamic dropdown from 1 table in different column but I couldn't find any tutorial which fit my needs

It has **orang_tua** table which has **n_ibu** and **n_ayah** but I don't know how to create dynamic dropdown

This is **orang_tua** table

```
CREATE TABLE `orang_tua` (
    `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `n_ibu` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `n_ayah` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `no_tlp` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `alamat` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
;
```

This is my **views** but can only show 1 column value in dropdown which is only **n_ibu**

```php
<option value="">-- Pilih dari daftar --</option>
<?php 
foreach($all_orang_tua as $orang_tua)
{
$selected = ($orang_tua['id'] == $this->input->post('id_orang_tua')) ? ' selected="selected"' : "";

echo '<option value="'.$orang_tua['id'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$orang_tua['n_ibu'].'</option>';
} 
?>
```

This is the **models**

```php
<?php

class Siswa_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /*
     * Get siswa by id
     */
    function get_siswa($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('siswa',array('id'=>$id))->row_array();
    }

    /*
     * Get all siswa
     */
    function get_all_siswa()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        return $this->db->get('siswa')->result_array();
    }

    /*
     * function to add new siswa
     */
    function add_siswa($params)
    {
        $this->db->insert('siswa',$params);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    /*
     * function to update siswa
     */
    function update_siswa($id,$params)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('siswa',$params);
    }

    /*
     * function to delete siswa
     */
    function delete_siswa($id)
    {
        return $this->db->delete('siswa',array('id'=>$id));
    }

    /*
     * custom function to show index siswa
     */
    function get_data_siswa()
    {
        $this->db->select('sw.id, sw.nama, sw.j_kelamin, sw.tmp_lahir, sw.tgl_lahir, sw.agama, sw.alamat, sw.no_tlp, sw.email, ot.n_ibu, ot.n_ayah, sk.nama_sek');
        $this->db->from('siswa sw');
        $this->db->join('orang_tua ot', 'ot.id=sw.id_orang_tua');
        $this->db->join('sekolah sk', 'sk.id=sw.id_sekolah');
        $this->db->distinct('siswa');
        return $this->db->get('siswa')->result_array();
    }
}
```

This is the **controllers**

```php
function add()
    {   
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','valid_email|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_orang_tua','Id Orang Tua','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_sekolah','Id Sekolah','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama','Nama','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('j_kelamin','J Kelamin','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tmp_lahir','Tmp Lahir','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tgl_lahir','Tgl Lahir','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('agama','Agama','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat','Alamat','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_tlp','No Tlp','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run())     
        {   
            $params = array(
                'j_kelamin' => $this->input->post('j_kelamin'),
                'id_orang_tua' => $this->input->post('id_orang_tua'),
                'id_sekolah' => $this->input->post('id_sekolah'),
                'nama' => $this->input->post('nama'),
                'tmp_lahir' => $this->input->post('tmp_lahir'),
                'tgl_lahir' => $this->input->post('tgl_lahir'),
                'agama' => $this->input->post('agama'),
                'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
                'no_tlp' => $this->input->post('no_tlp'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            );

            $siswa_id = $this->Siswa_model->add_siswa($params);
            redirect('siswa/index');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('Orang_tua_model');
            $data['all_orang_tua'] = $this->Orang_tua_model->get_all_orang_tua();

            $this->load->model('Sekolah_model');
            $data['all_sekolah'] = $this->Sekolah_model->get_all_sekolah();

            $data['_view'] = 'siswa/add';
            $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
        }
    }
```

This is **orang_tua_model**

```php
<?php

class Orang_tua_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /*
     * Get orang_tua by id
     */
    function get_orang_tua($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('orang_tua',array('id'=>$id))->row_array();
    }

    /*
     * Get all orang_tua
     */
    function get_all_orang_tua()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
        return $this->db->get('orang_tua')->result_array();
    }

    /*
     * function to add new orang_tua
     */
    function add_orang_tua($params)
    {
        $this->db->insert('orang_tua',$params);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    /*
     * function to update orang_tua
     */
    function update_orang_tua($id,$params)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('orang_tua',$params);
    }

    /*
     * function to delete orang_tua
     */
    function delete_orang_tua($id)
    {
        return $this->db->delete('orang_tua',array('id'=>$id));
    }
}
```

I really want to make 2 dropdowns which has relation from **n_ibu** so I can choose dropdown data from the same row which is **n_ayah** when I choose **n_ibu**. I'm still new in codeigniter and I hope that someone can help me

Comment: So you want 2 dropdown, first a `n_ibu` dropdown which if it's selected then set the `n_ayah` (from the same table row) as the second dropdown value?

Comment: Yes exactly because if someone have chosen the different value from another row, the the value won't be the same

Comment: @HastaDhana maybe you can help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to involve javascript for that functionality.
Consider you have set both `select` input like this :

```
<p>
<label for="ibu_select">Nama Ibu</label><br/>
<select name="id_orang_tua" id="ibu_select" >
    <option selected>-- Pilih dari daftar --</option>
    <?php 
    foreach($all_orang_tua as $orang_tua)
    {
    $selected = ($orang_tua['id'] == $this->input->post('id_orang_tua')) ? ' selected="selected"' : "";
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $orang_tua['id'] ?>" data-ayah="<?= $orang_tua['n_ayah'] ?>" <?= $selected ?> ><?= $orang_tua['n_ibu'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="ayah_select">Nama Ayah</label><br/>
<select name="n_ayah" id="ayah_select">
    <option id="ayah_select_val">-- Pilih dari daftar --</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Then you could use HTML `data-*` Attribute for this purpose since the `n_ayah` data is on the same row with `n_ibu` data, combined with the use of `onchange` event listener on the first dropdown input :

```
<script>

var selection = document.getElementById("ibu_select");
selection.onchange = function(event){
    var n_ayah = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.ayah;
    if (n_ayah) {
        document.getElementById("ayah_select_val").value = n_ayah;
        document.getElementById("ayah_select_val").text = n_ayah;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ayah_select_val").value = "";
        document.getElementById("ayah_select_val").text = "-- Pilih dari daftar --";
    }
};

</script>
```

The script will set the second dropdown value based from each of the first `data-` value respectively.

References :

- [HTML data-* Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp)
- [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: I've tried to use this but it didn't work. Here's my code https://pastebin.com/62jBu4QG. The first dropdown for ibu is working but it doesn't work for ayah

Comment: and the same for javascript. I should put this javascript on the same file right? I've done this but still the same

Comment: Yes exactly like that but I don't know why. Are you sure this code could fetch data from database?

Comment: You could try it without using any external js library first to check it, I'm afraid your additional library is replacing the actual option element so it won't work

Comment: You were right about it and do you know how to solve this? I'm using adminbsb bootstrap by the way

Comment: This is the screenshoot with js https://imgur.com/ymQXFlc and plain html https://imgur.com/7ygFIK9

Comment: After examining that adminbsb bootstrap template, I found out that adding an `ms` class to your `<select>` element will revert to using default bootstrap select style, try to make the `<select>` class like this : `class="form-control ms"`

Comment: You're rock! just a small thing can change everything

Answer (score 0):

**Implement below HTML & PHP script inside your view page for create dynamic dropdown.**

```
<select>
   <option value="">-- Pilih dari daftar --</option>
   <?php
   if(!empty($all_orang_tua))
   {
      foreach ($all_orang_tua as $orang_tua) 
      {
        $selectedValue="";
        if($orang_tua['id'] == $this->input->post('id_orang_tua'))
        {                                                          
           $selectedValue="selected";
        }
        ?>
        <option <?php echo $selectedValue;?> value="<?php echo $orang_tua['id'];?>"><?php echo $orang_tua['n_ibu'];?></option>
        <?php
      }
   }
   ?>
</select>
```

I hope using above code your problem will be resolved.

Comment: I'll try it and then I'll set as solved if it can work

Comment: I've tried but it's the same like my code before for `n_ibu` I mean I want to make chained dropdown from previous dropdown so I can choose `n_ayah` as chained dropdown from `n_ibu`. When I choose `n_ibu` then secodary dropdown will have the same value from the same row as `n_ibu` because `n_ayah` is in the same row

Comment: @MuhamadFikri Do you want to change the value in a drop down based second drop down? Can you explain by using example So that I can help you understand?

Comment: First `n_ibu` which if it's selected then set `n_ayah` from the same table row as the second dropdown value. Maybe you can read again my database so you can understand what I mean